# Symfony2, JMS Serializer, Doctrine Persistent Collection and FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to figure out how to return the DBRef objects in my views when using FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializer.

So in my document I have

```
class Advert {
    //...

    /**
     * @var Image[]
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="AppBundle\Document\Image", cascade={"persist", "update", "remove"})
     * @Serializer\Groups({"Default", "list", "details"})
     * @Serializer\AccessType("public_method")
     * @Serializer\Accessor(getter="getSerializableImages")
     */
    protected $images;

    //...
}
```

then, my controller looks like this

```
/**
 * @View(serializerGroups={"details"})
 * @ParamConverter("advert", class="AppBundle:Advert")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Advert $advert
 * @return array
 * @throws \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\LockException
 */
public function getAction(Request $request, Advert $advert)
{
    $this->get('monolog.logger.advert')->info('Advert View', [
        'documents' => [
            'advert' => $advert->toLoggableArray(),
        ],
    ]);

    $advertContact = new AdvertContact();
    $advertContact->setAdvert($advert);

    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\AdvertContact\AdvertContactType', $advertContact, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('advert_contact_new'),
        'method' => 'post',
    ]);

    return [
        'advert' => $advert,
        'contact_form' => $form->createView(),
    ];
}
```

I've been checking all over for solutions. Closest I came was with using JMS's `@Accessor` annotation, with a method that does `$this->images->toArray()` on the document, but that doesn't work properly and I'm concerned about deserialization.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what does `getSerializableImages` return? I'm guessing if it's not scalar then the serializer won't know how to serialize it

Comment: @mickadoo I tried to return `$this->images->toArray()` as suggested in other posts. It kind of worked, but returned the DBRef without the ID.

Comment: Could you try looping through the images and returning a key value array for each? I know this might not be the automatic serialization you want, but it might woek